# pandas column has 2 digit year and is getting converted to wrong 4 digit year

Tags: python, pandas

Date of birth column in my dataframe has two digit year. so any year that is 68 is giving me 2068 when converting the column to date type.

```
month_rep['dateofbirth'] = pd.to_datetime(month_rep['dateofbirth']).dt.date
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't know Pandas at all, but if this sort of problem keeps happening, I would recommend always using 4 digit years, which don't have any ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. That solved my problem.This helped:
future = month_rep['dateofbirth'] > datetime.today()
month_rep.loc[future, 'dateofbirth'] -= timedelta(days=365.25*100)